# what is the formula for 1000 separator in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a simple formula in a google sheet.

```
="Budget USD: "&SUM(D2:D)
```

This gives me `Budget USD: 13425`
what I want it to give me is `Budget USD: 13,425`
with the comma. Any help?

Comment: Not format, formula please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `FIXED` function

```
FIXED(number_of_decimals, suppress_separator)
```

for instance

```
="Budget USD: "&FIXED(SUM(D2:D),0)
```

to show the number with the thousands commas separator, zero decimals.

(of course you don't want to set `suppress_separator` to keep the thousands commas separator).

More information about [FIXED](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094075) from Google documentation.

Comment: @pnuts, your's is the one I tried first and it worked. Thanks. Also the answer of Ring Ø works fine as well. Thumbs up to you, but I am selecting this as the best answer.